# Is it worth to block inbound packets from a security standpoint?

Tags: linux, networking, security, firewall, iptables

If I block all the outgoing packets with iptables then in theory my system is safe since incoming packets won't be able to trigger data stealing. However those incoming packets can still exploit some a bug somewhere and deal either damage or bypass the iptables outgoing policy.

My question then is what is the most reasonable, convenient and secure way to manage incoming packages ? Should you block all incoming traffic and allow only trusted/needed servers, should you work on a blacklisting basis ? Another guess would be that everytime you send a SYN packet to a server, this server is automatically added to the whitelist so when you try to connect on a website it automatically allow him to reply. Is there a way to do such a thing conveniently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Another guess would be that everytime you send a SYN packet to a server, this server is automatically added to the whitelist so when you try to connect on a website it automatically allow him to reply. Is there a way to do such a thing conveniently ?

That's how most *stateful firewalls* work already (e.g. home routers because it's required for doing NAT, but common on servers too).

In [iptables](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html), this is done via the `conntrack` module or its simplified `state` version. Both examples are equivalent with modern kernels (although *I think* `-m state` was required in 2.6.x days).

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Though, IMHO, you should also unconditionally accept at least `-p icmp` and `-p ipv6-icmp`.

In [pf](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html#state), keeping state is the default for `pass` rules (unless `no state` was specified).

Comment: could you explain why you recommend accepting `-p icmp` and `-p ipv6-icmp`

Comment: I would like to know that as well since I see no benefit in doing it. Unless you want to let the world know you exist.

Comment: The world _already_ knows you exist, and doesn't find you important enough to care. No point in hiding that at the expense of losing a very useful debugging tool (ICMP Echo), breaking PMTUD (ICMP Fragment Too Large), breaking IPv6 (ICMPv6 ND), and so on.